# If $M,N$ are $R$-modules, then every submodule of $M \times N$ is the form of $U\times V,$ where $U,V$ are submodules of $M,N \ ?$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules and suppose $U$ and $V$ are submodules of $M$ and $N$ respectively. I have shown that $U \times V$ is submodule of $M \times N.$ May I know how do I prove/disprove that the converse is true?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the counterexample of the diagonal in $M \times M$. More concretely, let $M=N=R=\mathbb{R}$, then the vector space $\mathbb{R}\left(1,1\right)$ is a sub vector space of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which does not come from a "product" construction. Anyway you can do this construction for any module $M$ over a ring $R$ and this provides a counterexample, just use $\lbrace \left( x,x \right)|x \in M\rbrace$.

Comment: Hi can you explain more? I can't understand how this is a counterexample? Isn't $R(1,1) \in R \times R$? and since R = M = N, R is a submodules of M and N (not proper, of course).

Comment: @123 If we see $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, where the first $\mathbb{R}$ is supposed to be the $x$-axis and the second copy the $y$-axis, then $\mathbb{R}(1,1)$ cannot be obtained as a product of a submodule of the first copy times a submodule of the second copy. Assume it was possible, say $\mathbb{R}(1,1)=U \times V$. Then $U$ and $V$ must be nonzero. Pick $x \in U$ nonzero. Then $(x,0)\in U\times V$. But then, for how $\mathbb{R}(1,1)$ is, it would imply $x=0$ and hence a contradiction.